# PHP-code won't validate Captcha before posting

Tags: php, captcha

I am creating a Guestbook in PHP, each IP will only be able to post once.

Except for that it will require name and message before sending, and also CAPTCH validation. Somehow my code does ignore the Captcha validation as long as something is written in the input, regardless of what.

I have tried to save the captch in session, and validate the input for the captcha but it doesnt help.

Code to generate the captcha:

```
function generateCaptchaString($length = 5) {
$captchaString = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
   $_SESSION["captchaString"] = $captchaString;
     return $captchaString;
}
```

Code to input name, message and captcha:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" 
id="guestform">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Skriv i gästboken</legend>
                <label>Från: </label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Skriv ditt namn" 
name="name">
                <br>
                <label for="text">Inlägg</label>
                <textarea id="text" name="message"
                          rows="10" cols="50"
                          placeholder="Skriva meddelande här"></textarea>
                <br>

                <label>Captcha: <span class="red" id="captchastring"><?php 
echo  generateCaptchaString(); ?></span></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Skriva captcha här" 
name="captcha" id="captchainput" required>
                <button type="submit" id="submit">Skicka</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Code in the POST-function that will check for validation.

```
if( ! isset($_POST['captcha']) || empty($_POST['captcha']) || 
$_POST['captcha'] != $_SESSION['captcha']) {
    $error .= "<p class=\"message-error\">" . $messages['math_invalid'] . " 
</p>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `generateCaptchaString()` function, you store the captcha string in `$_SESSION["captchaString"]`.

But in the POST-validation code, you read it as: `$_SESSION['captcha']`

Change that into `$_SESSION["captchaString"]` as well.

Also, are you sure the URL to go to when submitting the form is `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` (which may be another .php script that includes or requires this one) rather than `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which is the same URL you're currently visiting.

Also, if the POST check code is in (or included by) the same file that also contains or includes the form, is it possible that `generateCaptchaString()` gets called again (to create the form again) thus overwriting any previous captchaString stored there?

Comment: Yes i have also been thinking maybe i am re-generating the Captcha, but if it were true, it should rather lead to that i never get a successful validation. The problem right now is that the script doesnt even use the validation I think. If it would, it would most likely give me "Wrong captcha" error all the time, til i find a way to not re-generate the captcha